# Cómo eliminar duplicados considerando tres columnas?

Tags: base-de-datos, r

Tengo un fichero como data.table dt1

```
   Longitud  Latitud   Altitud     ID
1 -2.89976   43.2165   195        C087
2 -2.99878   43.3062    5         C038
3 -2.21877   43.0520   195        G0E7
4 -2.10488   43.1018   190        G0E9
5 -2.99878   43.3062    5         C088
6 -2.21877   43.0520   195        G0A7
```

Como ven, tengo diferentes ID para la fila 2 y 5, y para las 3 y 6, pero entre ellas tienen las mismas coordenadas, con lo cual corresponde al mismo sitio pero con diferente nombre. Quisiera identificar en un fichero enorme todos estos casos para luego reemplazar los nombres y quitarme duplicados pero no sé como hacerlo poniendo más de una condición, pues tengo que identificar los ID que tengan exactamente iguales las tres coordenadas.  Estoy intentado sin éxito:

```
kk<-dt1[duplicated(Longitud&Latitud&Altitud),] 
kk<-dt1[duplicated(dt1$Longitud&dt1$Latitud&dt1$Altitud),]
```

Cómo debo hacerlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si revisas la documentación de [`duplicated()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/duplicated.html):

> **duplicated()** determines which elements of a vector or data frame are duplicates of elements with smaller subscripts, and returns a
>   logical vector indicating which elements (rows) are duplicates.

Por lo que de entrada ya se estaría esperando un `vector` o un objeto tipo `data.frame`. Conceptualmente los duplicados serían aquellas filas cuyas columnas exceptuando el `ID` son iguales, por lo que simplemente haces un "slice" del `data.frame` de las columnas de interés:

```
dt1[duplicated(dt1[, c("Latitud", "Longitud", "Altitud")]), ]
```

O incluso mejor, por ser mas generalizable

```
# Seleccionamos para duplicated() todas las variables menos ID
dt1[duplicated(dt1[, -which(names(dt1) == "ID")]), ]
```

El resultado sería:

```
  Longitud Latitud Altitud   ID
5 -2.99878 43.3062       5 C088
6 -2.21877 43.0520     195 G0A7
```

Como puedes observar, lo interesante es que los duplicados son las posteriores apariciones de los datos, por lo que, efectivamente, eliminando los duplicados, nos quedamos con los valores esperados:

```
# Negamos los valores duplicados
dt1[which(!duplicated(dt1[, -which(names(dt1) == "ID")])), ]

  Longitud Latitud Altitud   ID
1 -2.89976 43.2165     195 C087
2 -2.99878 43.3062       5 C038
3 -2.21877 43.0520     195 G0E7
4 -2.10488 43.1018     190 G0E9
```

En caso que quieras usas [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/index.html), puedes usar [`distinct()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/distinct.html), la sintaxis es un poco más sencilla y clara

```
library(dplyr)

dt1 %>%
    distinct(Longitud, Latitud, Altitud, .keep_all = TRUE)
```